# Transferring data between different sources using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, oracle, sql-server-ce

I have 1 table in an Oracle database and another table in a SqlCe database. Both tables are called the same and I would like to transfer all the content of table in SqlCe database to the same table in Oracle database using SqlBulkCopy available in .NET Framework.

I know that using SqlBulkCopy it is possible to transfer any data from any source into a Sql database but I am not sure if it is possible from Sql database (in my case, SqlCe) to any source, for example, from SqlCe to Oracle. Could someone confirm me if it is possible?

Comment: I think that is not possible. I have faced such problem and i solved through SqlBulkCopy but from file. I export data from one database into file and then i import in the other database through SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use `SqlBulkCopy`, as that is tied to SQL Server's connection protocol (TDS); however, since the target is oracle, `OracleBulkCopy` should work fine. You would simply use `ExecuteReader` on the SqlCe source, and feed that in:

```
using(var target = new OracleBulkCopy(oracleConnectionString))
using(var source = cecmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    target.DestinationTableName = "Foo";
    target.WriteToServer(source);
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm

Comment: +1 Nice solution. I have followed something more difficult. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: OracleBulkCopy is not contained in .NET Framework. As I have seen this is included in Oracle Data Provider for .NET that I need to download from Oracle, right?

Comment: @user1624552 I'm afraid I do now know